# Java Code for writing Long Array to file

Tags: java

I got a code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249718/write-compressed-array-to-increase-io-performance) to write a Int array to file. However, I am trying to convert it thus it can write Long array to file. But, it gives error (code given below). Can anybody help me why  it is giving error and what should be the corrected code. Thanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class Test {
    private static final int bucketSize = 1<<17;//in real world should not be const, but we bored horribly
    static final int zipLevel = 2;//feel free to experiement, higher compression (5+)is likely to be total waste


 static void writes(long[] a, File file, boolean sync) throws IOException{
        byte[] bucket = new byte[Math.min(bucketSize,  Math.max(1<<13, Integer.highestOneBit(a.length >>3)))];//128KB bucket
        byte[] zipOut = new byte[bucket.length];

        final FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        FileChannel channel = fout.getChannel();
        try{

            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bucket);
            //unfortunately java.util.zip doesn't support Direct Buffer - that would be the perfect fit
            ByteBuffer out = ByteBuffer.wrap(zipOut);
            out.putLong(a.length);//write length aka header
            if (a.length==0){
                doWrite(channel, out, 0);
                return;
            }

            Deflater deflater = new Deflater(zipLevel, false);
            try{
                for (int i=0;i<a.length;){
                    i = puts(a, buf, i);
                    buf.flip();
                    deflater.setInput(bucket, buf.position(), buf.limit());

                    if (i==a.length)
                        deflater.finish();

                    //hacking and using bucket here is tempting since it's copied twice but well
                    for (int n; (n= deflater.deflate(zipOut, out.position(), out.remaining()))>0;){
                        doWrite(channel, out, n);
                    }
                    buf.clear();
                }

            }finally{
                deflater.end();
            }
        }finally{
            if (sync)
                fout.getFD().sync();
            channel.close();
        }
    }

    static long[] reads(File file) throws IOException, DataFormatException{
        FileChannel channel = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
        try{
            byte[] in = new byte[(int)Math.min(bucketSize, channel.size())];
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(in);

            channel.read(buf);
            buf.flip();
            long[] a = new long[(int)buf.getLong()];
            if (a.length==0)
                return a;
            int i=0;
            byte[] inflated = new byte[Math.min(1<<17, a.length*4)];
            ByteBuffer intBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(inflated);
            Inflater inflater = new Inflater(false);
            try{
                do{
                    if (!buf.hasRemaining()){
                        buf.clear();
                        channel.read(buf);
                        buf.flip();
                    }
                    inflater.setInput(in, buf.position(), buf.remaining());
                    buf.position(buf.position()+buf.remaining());//simulate all read

                    for (;;){
                        int n = inflater.inflate(inflated,intBuffer.position(), intBuffer.remaining());
                        if (n==0)
                            break;
                        intBuffer.position(intBuffer.position()+n).flip();
                        for (;intBuffer.remaining()>3 && i<a.length;i++){//need at least 4 bytes to form an int
                            a[i] = intBuffer.getInt();
                        }
                        intBuffer.compact();
                    }

                }while (channel.position()<channel.size() && i<a.length);
            }finally{
                inflater.end();
            }
            //          System.out.printf("read ints: %d - channel.position:%d %n", i, channel.position());
            return a;
        }finally{
            channel.close();
        }
    }

    private static void doWrite(FileChannel channel, ByteBuffer out, int n) throws IOException {
        out.position(out.position()+n).flip();
        while (out.hasRemaining())
            channel.write(out);
        out.clear();
    }
    private static int puts(long[] a, ByteBuffer buf, int i) {
        for (;buf.hasRemaining() && i<a.length;){
            buf.putLong(a[i++]);
        }
        return i;
    }





    private static long[] generateRandom(int len){
        Random r = new Random(17);
        long[] n = new long [len];
        for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
            n[i]= r.nextBoolean()?0: r.nextInt(1<<23);//limit bounds to have any sensible compression
        }
        return n;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable{
        File file = new File("xxx.xxx");
        long[] n = generateRandom(3000000); //{0,2,4,1,2,3};
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        writes(n, file, false);
        long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;//elapsed will be fairer if the sync is true

        System.out.printf("File length: %d, for %d ints, ratio %.2f in %.2fms %n", file.length(), n.length, ((double)file.length())/4/n.length, java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(elapsed, 6) );

        long[] m = reads(file);

        //compare, Arrays.equals doesn't return position, so it sucks/kinda
        for (int i=0; i<n.length; i++){
            if (m[i]!=n[i]){
                System.err.printf("Failed at %d%n",i);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("All done!");
    };

}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to sift through. Could you tell us what error occurs at least?

Comment: @corsiKa, it gives error that write array and read array are not same.

Comment: **please**, put in some thought how it works, I will hint the most obvious '>3' must be ..., sizeof(long)==8 not 4, etc.

Comment: @corsiKa, the error is pretty obvious, if you run it, actually but it's visible on the screen just as well.

Comment: @bestsss The error probably is pretty obvious, it's just the idea that if OP says there's an error he should generally put the error in the post.

Comment: @Arpssss Along the same lines as bestsss's note of `>3`, you might want to consider `Math.min(1<<17, a.length*4)` (note the 4...). It's reasons like this that 'magic numbers' aren't so good in your code.

Comment: @corsiKa, *4 won't matter so much even if it' *8,actually any value above 8 will produce no exception, it's buffer size optimization. Bit twiddling w/ named constants sometimes is too annoying, esp. with constant sized primitives in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I took a few minutes to actually run the code, and it took a little tweaking from your posted code, but here it is.

One thing I did that was -unnecessary- was change `intBuffer` to `longBuffer`, just for clarity's sake. It's part of the first difference

```
75  -  byte[] inflated = new byte[Math.min(1<<17, a.length*4)];
76  -  ByteBuffer intBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(inflated);
76  +  byte[] inflated = new byte[Math.min(1<<17, a.length*8)];
77  +  ByteBuffer longBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(inflated);
```

In the above snippet, I change the length of the inflated buffer to a.length*8 to reflect it being a long array instead of an int array.

```
89  -  int n = inflater.inflate(inflated,intBuffer.position(), intBuffer.remaining());
90  +  int n = inflater.inflate(inflated,longBuffer.position(), longBuffer.remaining());
```

This is only a change to the variable name.

```
92  -  intBuffer.position(intBuffer.position()+n).flip();
93  -  for (;intBuffer.remaining()>3 && i<a.length;i++){//need at least 4 bytes to form an int
94  -      a[i] = intBuffer.getInt();
93  +  longBuffer.position(longBuffer.position()+n).flip();
94  +  for (;longBuffer.remaining()>7 && i<a.length;i++){//need at least 4 bytes to form an int
95  +      a[i] = longBuffer.getLong();
```

This is a very important change. First the name was changed, but that's not the important part. Second, the `remaining()` is 7 instead of 3, as bestsss pointed out. Lastly, **a[i] is now getting a long instead of an int.**. That's the biggest problem, for sure.

```
96  -  intBuffer.compact();
97  +  longBuffer.compact();
```

Just a renaming here.

```
142 -  System.out.printf("File length: %d, for %d ints, ratio %.2f in %.2fms %n", file.length(), n.length, ((double)file.length())/4/n.length, java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(elapsed, 6) );
143 +  System.out.printf("File length: %d, for %d ints, ratio %.2f in %.2fms %n", file.length(), n.length, ((double)file.length())/8/n.length, java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(elapsed, 6) );
```

This is just on the file output to get an idea of the compression, it's now computing the number of results from the file.length / 8 instead of over 4.

And those are the only necessary edits I had to make to get it to work. Basically just moving from int to long in all places.

Full code is here in a pastebin in case you muck-up the diff notation or something: http://pastebin.com/emY14Ji4

Note: the line numbers in my copy (+) are one higher than your copy (-) because of a debug statement I didn't remove... whoops...

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine. One thing I cannot get from the discussion, is bucket size have any effect on performance or not ?

Comment: Actually, I have to write 220 million Int/Long, for this the above code is little bit slower. So, confused.

Comment: It would appear that the current way the code works, reducing bucketsize to something very small, let's say `1<<5` would simply make you have fewer items brought in at a time, so it would be slower. I made some small adaptations to it so I could pass the `1<<x` number in as a parameter. The results http://pastebin.com/sVX6FB0v indicate that after `1<<10` you don't gain significant, reliable performance.

Comment: IF you're running on a 32 bit machine, this code will be slower than the int code. Longs take longer to work with than ints do on 32 bit machines (or on 32 bit programs running in 64 bit machines.) Unless you're using 64 bit hardware and software, you'll go faster with the int based code.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks a lot. Now, I am experimenting with zip level.

Comment: *Always* change the relevant comments when changing the code.

Comment: To build upon bestsss comment, try to put comments that won't need changing when you change the code. `// acquire our value` or `// acquire our data` might be better than `// acquire our int`. Never believe for a second that you'll ever write code you won't have to change. If you never would need to change it, you wouldn't bother keeping the source, would you?

Comment: @corsiKa, funny part is that *I* did the code, and that code should have had teaching value, not a repost one - "how to change the int into a long". Look at the link in the question ('here') and scroll down (unless you have sorted by activity)

Comment: @bestsss If I had a dollar for every time I *didn't* follow the advice I give other people, even just when it comes to programming, I could retire. :) It's easy to say "Think about the future" when you have a project in the present!

Answer (score -2):

Don't use a byte buffer, instead use an ObjectOutputStream to store the veriable to the file, and a ObjectInputStream to read from it.  I believe the issue is that you're not holding the "Long" definition throughout the process.

ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream can read/write any data type.

Comment: Sorry. I need to modify above code thus it works for long. I need to check performance with other writing/reading methods.

Comment: the answer is not right in any way.